# how to highlight only one table td on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Hello i have a table and i want to highlight table td when i click it. I managed to make it work but only on half. It change's the td when i select another but only on that row, what i want is to select only 1 td. Here is my js code

```
<script>
        $(".table").on("click", "td", function() {      
             $(this).closest("td").siblings().removeClass("td_select"); 
             $(this).toggleClass("td_select"); 
             $("#basicModal").modal("show");
       });

</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3umm7w8/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you need this:

```
 $(this).closest("table").find('td').removeClass("td_select"); 
 //in the current table, find all cells, and remove the highlight
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/d3umm7w8/2/

Comment: I'd probably recommend adding a quick check just so you don't bother deselecting and reselecting if the user clicks a cell that is already highlighted. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/d3umm7w8/4/).